# Ошибка. jQuery загружает изображение не через HTTPS, а через HTTP

Tags: веб-программирование, https, img, site

Подскажите пожалуйста. Ломаю голову, как исправить.

На сайте (Opencart) не включается https из-за смешанного контента. Показывает, мол jQuery загружает картинку через HTTP.

[image: Ошибка]

Открываю файл, но совершенно не понимаю, что тут исправлять

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, советом. В какую сторону смотреть

Comment: какой код и как назначает `img.src`? Или это фон?

Comment: @Igor это картинка - анимация, которая отображается при загрузке. Сам я не назначал src, это готовый шаблон opencart. В самих tpl-файлах я заменил адрес на https. Но адреса ведь должны быть относительными во всех файлах. А все настройки в конфигах изменены на https и никаких проблем, кроме этой, нет.

Comment: @Igor я проверил все JS-файлы, которые отвечают за модуль ocajaxregister, выполнил поиск по url, но там только относительные